# Define a class method of a class that is inside another file?

Tags: python, class, methods

**Both of my files are in the same folder, can i do something like this using an import statement maybe?**

#File 1 (1.py)

```
class MyClass():
    def __init__(self):
        pass

    def my_method_1(self):
        pass
```

#File 2 (2.py)

```
def my_method2(self): #make this be a method of the MyClass class in file 1
    pass
```

Comment: In general you *can* add methods onto existing classes, but what's the context here - why do you need to patch it rather than e.g. extending it?

Comment: this looks a lot like "monkey patching" and is generally discouraged in general development practices as it makes it much more difficult to track down what the code is doing